# Query not displaying anything when going to new year

Tags: mysql, sql

Everything works fine when I place my date range in the same year.  For example, using 12-01-2015 to 12-31-2015 its all good.  But when I attempt to use 12-01-2015 to 01-30-2016, it returns with 0 results.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT "Glass Separating From Frame", count('x') from returns
INNER JOIN orders
ON orders.orderid = returns.orderid
WHERE returns.productcode in (189000, 182003) AND 
from_unixtime(orders.init_date, "%m-%d-%Y") between "MM-DD-YYYY" and "MM-DD-YYYY"
and returns.returnid NOT IN (56116, 57823)
and returns.internal_notes LIKE "%Glass Separating From Frame%"
```

MySQL.

Comment: I think `from_unixtime` [returns a number or string depending on context](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) so you are doing string comparison, in which case your date isn't between your two supplied dates, alphabetically speaking. Change your format to `%Y-%m-%d` and you'll probably get what you are looking for.

Comment: As @JNevill has said, the result of your current operation are strings that are compared lexicographically in which your dates are not ordered as expected.  However, rather than format as `Y-m-d`, it'd be better still to store `init_date` as a `DATE` and just use regular date literals; or, if that's not possible, then converting your literals to UNIX timestamps with [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) and comparing the result directly against the values stored in `init_date` would be more sargable than your current approach.

Comment: You can also convert the inputs (the betweens) to unixtimes and be out of trouble

Comment: Yes. You have said that and your comment was earlier. However I did not see your comment till now. Android cellular client. If my comment offends you I'll remove it

Comment: Thanks JNevill that worked!